# Extension to allow mouseless browsing in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, software-rec, google-chrome-extensions

Does anyone know of an extension for Google Chrome that puts numbers (1-99) next to each link like the "Mouseless Browsing" add-on for Firefox that allows you to select links with the keyboard?

I don't use a keyboard. In Firefox I can just say a number to navigate links. I wish I could do it in Chrome.

Comment: i don't understand your PS

Comment: If you're on Windows, have you tried the native voice commands?

Answer (score 5):

The one you probably want is [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en).

Answer (score 4):

first result for "keyboard navigation" in the chrome-extension-store yields ... "[keyboard navigation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/abcekjakjehkpheoaadhkjfcdodpjbgk)":

> The Keyboard Navigation extension allows you to browse the web without
>   using a mouse.
>
> How it works: 1) Press the comma key (,) to start. This will show
>   hints for every link, textbox ... 2) Type a hint. If you typed
>   correctly, the hint will be highlighted. 3) Press Enter or Return to
>   "click" on the highlighted element.

[image]

if you want control your chrome with your voice only (something i can only assume since you don't make that idiot-proof-clear), maybe something like http://www.chromevoicecontrol.com/index.html could be used in combination with "keyboard navigation".

Comment: he said that he does not use a keyboard... so I think he's looking for a speech extension

Comment: his first paragraph states that he wants something like the mouseless-addon from firefox .. "that allows you to select links with the keyboard". when OP wants to combine speach-control with whatever the browser displays .. fine, he should mention it / highlight that aspect of the question a bit more, eg 'i want to navigate my chrome by voice'.

Comment: don't you have read the content then? :P the PS (post scriptum) states that he did not use a keyboard so probably he's looking for a speech extension... anyway I can agree with you that it will be more appropriate if it's on the title or on the first paragraph ;)

Comment: @Marcx: i did read the PS, as stated in my comment on the question i just don't understand it's meaning and relevance to the question by reading it.

Answer (score 2):

[cVim](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cvim/ihlenndgcmojhcghmfjfneahoeklbjjh) is my absolute favourite.